# Why do I need to use Dynamic in order for Plot to work?

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I have a problem. I'm on 13.3.

I have setup an expression in the following manner:

```
F /: f[F, {x_, y_}] := x y (* x*y is an example of a specific functional form *)
```

This is supposed to be interpreted as "*please, perform calculation `f` on expression `F` that is depended on arguments `x` and `y`*"; the reason I chose this representation is because, in the future, it will be possible to perform different calculations (eg `g` and `h`, in addition to `f`) on (probably other) `F`'s (too).

This is not really important, however it presents the motivation behind the code implementation.

Now, I am pretty certain, that before 13.3 you could actually pull something like this off:

```
(* plot is a customized plotting function; it is built around Plot *)
plot[g_, {x_, y_}] := Plot[g[x], {x, 1, y}]

(* this evaluation is expected to produce 2 plots, one for y -> 2 and another for y -> 3 *)
plot[f[F, {#, y}] &, {x, y}] /. {{y -> 2}, {y -> 3}}
```

Unfortunately, there are no plots generated, or if I have to be precise, there are exactly two empty plots generated, somewhat resembling the following:

[image]

I have tried several "*tricks*" to make it work, however nothing worked *except* something that is really counterintuitive to my understanding of *Mathematica* (or WL) code, at least up until 13.3 was released.

Changing the `plot` function into this, seemed to work:

```
plot[g_, {x_, y_}] := Dynamic @ Plot[g[x], {x, 1, y}]
```

(I suppose you can see the `Dynamic` in there, right?)

Now it produces the desired plots:

```
plot[g_, {x_, y_}] := Plot[g[x], {x, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

However I don't understand why this happens and what's more important I don't understand why I need to use `Dynamic` in the first place.

Any suggestions, explanations etc are REALLY welcome.

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with version 13.3 (the same behaviour is present in other versions). The problem is in your evaluation order: `plot` is evaluated before `y` is inserted (and it has nowhere to be inserted anymore because `plot` returned an empty plot). There are various different solutions, for example using `Hold`: `Hold@plot[f[F, {#, y}] &, {x, y}] /. {{y -> 1}, {y -> 2}} // ReleaseHold` or `Table[plot[f[F, {#, y}] &, {x, y}], {y, {1, 2}}]` or some other ways of preventing `plot` to be converted to `Plot` prematurely.

Comment: @Domen ok I see your point; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so this is an answer based on the comment from @Domen.

The problem in the original question is with the order of evaluation.

In

```
plot[f[F, {#, y}] &, {x, y}] /. {{y -> 2}, {y -> 3}}
```

`plot` never sees the `y` value because it has already been evaluated to

```
Plot[(f[F, {#, y}] &)[x], {x, 1, y}]
```

which in turn cannot plot because `y` does not have a numeric value.

The proposed solution is to use `Hold` and `ReleaseHold`:

```
Hold @ plot[f[F, {#, y}] &, {x, y}] /. {{y -> 2}, {y -> 3}} // ReleaseHold
```

This way, the evaluation gives the expected plots

[image]